# Setting up facebook login in swift

Tags: swift, facebook

I have been trying to setup an facebook login in my app.

In the guide I'm following from facebook, it says I need to import this:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

I have downloaded the IOS SDK folder which I took the Corekit folder and dragged it into my project in xcode, however when I create a objective c file and insert the line, it says:

"FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found."

Comment: may be you are adding the wrong folder . try to copy files into project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the "copy items if needed" checkbox ?

If you didn't you have to add framework search path in your project settings

Comment: I did add the search path as well... I can't see what I'm missing... I'm just its a simple mistake somewhere..

Comment: what's the content of you Framework Search Path setting ? Is the Facebook framework located in one of those ?

Comment: I fixed it. The path I had written in the search path was wrong. (even though I double checked it, I didn't see it) .

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is better to include header files to the bridging header and then use method by swift way (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Then I would prefer to install FB through cocoapods.

If you insist on your solution then check Header Serch Paths in project > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths.